# Terminal && Non Terminal recursive call

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

Can anyone tell ma about difrence between   Terminal recursive call  and Non  Terminal recursive call??

i wrote

```
#include <iostream>

int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n==0 || n==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

Comment: So you wrote a code... how does it relate to the question?

Comment: Welcome 2bo to Stack Overflow. I recommend you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so you get better responses to your question. Like proof read before posting. Be clear about what you need and what you tried and you will get help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Terminal recursion happens when the recursive call is the very last operation to be done in the function.

Non-terminal recursion happens when there is additional work to do upon returning from the recursive call.

Your example is non-terminal, because after returning from the recursive call there is still a multiplication to be done (the `n*`). The last line:

```
return n*factorial(n-1)
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
int temp = factorial(n-1);
return temp * n;
```

You can change the `factorial()` function to be terminal with additional arguments:

```
int factorial_x(int n, int f)
{
    if (n==0 || n==1)
        return f;
    else
        return factorial_x(n - 1, f * n);
}
int factorial(int n)
{
    return factorial_x(n, 1);
}
```

The recursive call:

```
return factorial_x(n - 1, f * n);
```

is equivalent to:

```
int n2 = n - 1;
int f2 = f * n;
return factorial(n2, f2);
```

As you can see, now the multiplication is before the recursive call, not after. Afer the recursive call there is nothing, just the `return`, so this is truely tail recursion.

Comment: and terminal recursion is an important concept because it can be optimised: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call

Comment: The terminal code won't work as `factorial_x` doesn't have any base condition and will go on recursively and give stackoverflow error.